# Used AJAX to update webpage - how do I change the URL too?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I've used the following tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

I'm using it to change the page async - however, I also want to make it so that the new URL is generated.

(at the moment when a user clicks on a button it adds a # to the URL while displaying a different page, how do I make it so that the URL reflects the page that was added but remain the update async?)

**HTML :**

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadDoc('{{site.url}}/webpage.html')" id="#my-link"> Use “Just Enough” </a></h5>
```

**JS :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function loadDoc(contentURL) {
         var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("prinDesc").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
         };
         xhttp.open("GET", contentURL, true);
         xhttp.send();
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) in the [browsers where it is supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history).

Updated `loadDoc` function:

```
function loadDoc(contentURL) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("prinDesc").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;

      window.history && window.history.pushState({}, '', contentURL);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", contentURL, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm using Jekyll and when I send a link it no longer renders the website properly (it just displays Mark Down) - I don't suppose you know how to fix this?

Comment: This would have to do with the backend setup I'm afraid. However – I did noticed my proposed solution assumes relative URLs (`/webpage.html` instead of `{{site.url}}/webpage.html`) if that helps in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could with HTML5 using `history.pushState`.

> **[pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) :**
>
> takes three parameters: a state object, a title (which is currently ignored), and (optionally) a URL.

**Example :**

Use it inside your success callback :

```
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("prinDesc").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    window.history.pushState('Object', 'New Page Title', '/new-url');
}
```

For more information please visit **[Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)**.

**NOTE :** Never trust *w3schools* and never use it as reference here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should include a note that the OP shouldn't be using w3schools